# If i wanted to extract the ttl and display it from the ping command how could i go about doing that?

Tags: bash, scripting, ping, ttl

Scripting and want to ping devices on a network, tell me if it's reachable or not, and then get the ttl data from the ping and tell me the operating system.

Ive tried using the awk command, but I am also new to scripting and may not be using it correctly.

```
for host in $(seq 1 255);   
do
    ping -c 1 $sn.$host | grep "Unreachable" &>/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$sn.$host is Offline"
    fi

    ping -c 1 $sn.$host | grep "ttl" &>/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$sn.$host is Online"
    fi
done
```

I need the ttl value and to store it into a variable and then tell me what operating system it is based on Linux has a ttl of 64, windows a ttl of 128, and ios of 255

Comment: That's possibly not a *reliable* way of detecting, especially since TTL can change based on network path (which can change at any point). For example, if I ping my host Windows from my Ubuntu VM, I get `127`, while I get `128` by pinging my colleague's box from the same VM.

Answer (score 1):

You can do things in a bit more concise manner and minimize the time waiting for an Offline host by setting a *timeout* using the `-w` (or `-W`) option. For example you can save the `ttl=XX` value from `ping` in the same call that determines whether the host is online or not and then you can use a simple *parameter expansion* to extract the numeric `ttl` value from the right side of the equal sign, e.g.

```
    ttlstr=$(ping -c1 -w1 $sn.$host | grep -o 'ttl=[0-9][0-9]*')
```

Above the *command substitution* `$(...)` executes `ping` and pipes the output to `grep` and assigns the results to `ttlstr`. The command substitution return is the return of the last command in the pipeline telling you whether `grep` for `"ttl=####"` succeeded or failed. That's all you need to determine whether the host is online or not. On failure output your `"Offline"` message and try the next, e.g.

```
    ## ping with 1 sec timeout store ttl=xx in ttlstr
    ttlstr=$(ping -c1 -w1 $sn.$host | grep -o 'ttl=[0-9][0-9]*') || {
        printf "%s is Offline\n" "$sn.$host"
        continue;
    }
```

If the command substitution succeeds, you can output your "Online" message and you can isolate the numeric `ttl` using a simple *parameter expansion* to remove all characters up to, and including, the `'='` sign from the beginning of the string leaving only the numeric `ttl`, e.g.

```
    ttl="${ttlstr#*=}"  ## parameter expansion separating numeric ttl
    printf "%s is Online, ttl=%d\n" "$sn.$host" "$ttl"
```

Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

sn=${1:-192.168.6}

for host in $(seq 1 255); do
    ## ping with 1 sec timeout store ttl=xx in ttlstr
    ttlstr=$(ping -c1 -w1 $sn.$host | grep -o 'ttl=[0-9][0-9]*') || {
        printf "%s is Offline\n" "$sn.$host"
        continue;
    }
    ttl="${ttlstr#*=}"  ## parameter expansion separating numeric ttl
    printf "%s is Online, ttl=%d\n" "$sn.$host" "$ttl"
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

**note:** the `sn` is taken as the 1st argument to the program (using a default of `192.168.6` above)

```
$ bash ~/scr/utl/chksubnet.sh
<snip>
192.168.6.14 is Offline
192.168.6.15 is Offline
192.168.6.16 is Offline
192.168.6.17 is Online, ttl=64
192.168.6.18 is Offline
192.168.6.19 is Offline
<snip>
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Wow.  I wish I could 1-up you more than once - I really like the code and the prose.  And I'm so happy to see you do it outside of awk.

Comment: Thank you @Mark. There is always more than one way to skin-the-cat in shell scripting. Over the years you just kind of pick up the finer points of the various ways you can put things together. (what I called adding it to my toolbox) As with anything, the more time you spend with a subject, the more tools you tend to collect in your toolbox `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of using awk to extract the ttl:

```
$ ping -c 1  8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=48.575 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 48.575/48.575/48.575/0.000 ms


$ ping -c 1  8.8.8.8 | awk -F'[ =]' '/ttl/ {print $8 }'
53
```

The -F parameter tells awk what the field separator is.  I've indicated spaces or the equals sign.  The body of the awk script is written as pattern / command pairs.  In the one line script, awk runs the print $8 command for any line that has ttl in line.  The command tells awk to print the eigth field (remember, the -F indicated how to break the input line into fields.  The /ttl/ pattern could be replaced with $7 == "ttl", too.  This latter form is more accurate, since it would only match ttl if it appeared as the 7th field.

There are better more general implementations.

If you want to do this quickly, review the nmap utility.  For example,

```
nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24
```

Nmap aside, your program can be improved a bit by ping'ing the IP once and piping the results to awk, letting awk generate ALL the output.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the script which you can use to find the Operating System name based on the ttl value if host is Online.

```
   for host in $(seq 1 255);
    do
        ping -c 1 $sn.$host | grep "Unreachable" &>/dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
            printf "%s\n" "$sn.$host is Offline"
            continue
        else
            printf "%s\n" "$sn.$host is Online" 
            ttlValue=`ping -c 1 $sn.$host | grep ttl | awk '{print $6}'|awk -F'=' '{print $2}' &>/dev/null`
            if [ $ttlValue -eq 64 ]
            then
                echo "Operating is Linux"
            elif [ $ttlValue -eq 128 ]
            then
                echo "Operating is Windows"
            else
                echo "Operating is IOS"
            fi
        fi
    done
```